# Python - how to make dynamic method

Tags: python, dynamicmethod

I wonder how i can assign dynamic method (for example ".text" or ".split()") to my variable.

```
some_selector = "div.test"      # is it possible to add here a method? For example ".text"
soup.select_one(some_selector).text   # It would work, i want to achieve this, but in line above ( i don't want to have .text in this line).
```

Ideal solution (but it's not working):

```
some_selector = "div.test".text  # i added at the end of the sentence method
soup.select_one(some_selector)
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this? You can probably hack something together using `eval`, but it's not going to be pretty

Comment: `.text` in case 1 has different basis vs case 2, in case 2, the basis is 'div.test', in case 1, the basis is the result of `soup.select_one(some_selector)`, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: learning purpose

Comment: I think you need `my_select_one(some_selector) = select_one(some_selector).text`

Comment: case 1 and case 2, each of the `.text` gets evaluated at different point.